# Zwei -em-Endungen in Adjektiven hintereinander

Tags: adjective, dative, adjective-ending, list

Ein Zitat vom Tagesspiegel:

> Erkennbar sei sie an: übertriebenem Selbstwertgefühl, ständigem Verlangen nach Bewunderung, Mangel an Einfühlungsvermögen und arrogante**m**, überhebliche**n** Verhalten.

Müsste es nicht *überhebliche**m*** heißen und wenn nein, warum?

Comment: Ich würde auch für *überheblichem* plädieren, weil es einfach eine zweite Eigenschaft des *Verhaltens* ist. Der Satz ist insgesamt allerdings keine Großtat der Formulierungskunst, weil *arrogant* und *überheblich* synonym sind - ich würde eines von beiden streichen und durch eine Betonung wie *sehr* ersetzen.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass durch das Wiederholen versucht wird, diese Eigenschaft hervorzuheben. Genau so wie es auch "Immer und ewig" tut

Comment: Habe gerade in der FAZ diese schöne dreifache Wiederholung gefunden: Jemand bekam _den größten Applaus, weil er klare, deutliche und unmissverständliche Worte gefunden hatte._

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es gibt keine *Norm*, derzufolge es *überhebliche**m*** heißen *muss*.

In "Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 7. Aufl. Mannheim 2011" (das ist die aktuelle Auflage, soweit ich sehe), heißt es:

> Selbstverständlich kann der Schreiber das Mittel der Parallel- und der Wechselflexion bewusst einsetzen, um Neben- bzw. Unterordnung der Adjektive zu signalisieren. Eine normative Regelung ist deshalb ausgeschlossen. Ein Komma zwischen den Adjektiven kann sowohl bei Parallel- wie auch bei Wechselflexion gesetzt werden (nach langem, heftigem Streit; nach langem, heftigen Streit).

(Zitiert nach einer Antwort auf [korrekturen.de](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/58833/sbj/nach-langem-schwerem-n-leiden/). Ich habe die Originalquelle leider nicht zur Hand, mittlerweile wurde das Zitat bestätigt. Siehe aber den Hinweis weiter unten.)

Bemerkenswert finde ich an diesem Zitat zweierlei:

- Es fehlt die Empfehlung zur Parallelflexion, die [möglicherweise schon seit 1966](http://www.spiegel.de/forum/kultur/zwiebelfisch-ist-unsere-sprache-ein-schwerer-pflegefall-thread-180-1714.html#postbit_2212957) die frühere strikte Unterscheidung nach Neben- und Unterordnung der Adjektive ersetzt hatte. **Update**: @Loong hat die Quelle überprüft und weist darauf hin, dass für das gewählte Beispiel doch die Schreibweise *nach langem, heftigem Streit* empfohlen wird. Die Passage fehlt offenbar in dem Zitat.
- Obwohl der Duden hier anscheinend wieder recht stark auf die "alte" Regel (laut Takkats Antwort ins Jahr 1935 zurückreichende) Unterscheidung nach Neben- und Unterordnung Bezug nimmt, erlaubt er auch für den Fall, dass beide Adjektive durch Komma getrennt sind (was ja eher für Nebenordnung sprechen würde), ausdrücklich auch den Gebrauch der Wechselflexion.

Ich würde allerdings auch *überhebliche**m*** schreiben, denn das passt zu den Regeln, mit denen ich aufgewachsen bin.

Comment: Die Quellenangabe (Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 7. Aufl. Mannheim 2011) ist korrekt. Allerdings fehlt der Hinweis, dass der Ausdruck „nach langem, heftigem Streit“ in der Quelle als „von der Dudenredaktion empfohlen“ gekennzeichnet ist.

Comment: @Loong Ich hatte gehofft, dass Du Dich melden würdest ;-) Danke für den Hinweis, ich habe das ergänzt.

Answer (score 12):

Man findet durchaus nicht selten eine wechselnde starke und schwache Flexion von artikellosen Adjektiven im Dativ Singular.

> Einen Whatsapp-Account zu missbrauchen, sich einzuhacken, das sei dann doch ziemlich kompliziert und mit großem technischen Aufwand verbunden.<sup>Rhein-Zeitung 2014</sup>

Da sich die Grammatikregeln an den Sprachgebrauch halten (und nicht umgekehrt), sind auch beide Varianten erlaubt, es gibt keine verbindliche Regel, wonach die eine oder die andere Variante richtig wäre.

Rein grammatikalisch-logisch sollte man aber zumindest bei durch Komma oder Konjunktion getrennten Adjektiven wie im Beispiel in der Frage **bevorzugt die starke Flexion beider Adjektive** anwenden.

Interessant in diesem Zusammenhang ist eine Duden-Regel aus dem Jahr 1935, nach der die gemischte Flexion empfohlen wurde, wenn das zweite Adjektiv eine begriffliche Einheit mit dem Nomen bildet (*überhebliches Verhalten*), die dann durch das erste Adjektiv näher spezifiziert wird. Diese Regel ist zwar heute nicht mehr verbindlich, wird aber vielleicht immer noch angewandt.

---

Quelle: [IDS Mannheim: Mit echtem bayerischem Senf oder mit echtem bayerischen Senf?](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/44)

Comment: Dein Beispiel unterscheidet sich aber klar von Barths: der Aufwand ist nicht groß und technisch, sondern der technische Aufwand ist groß. Dagegen ist "überheblich" eben nicht stärker mit "Verhalten" verbunden als "arrogant", man könnte z.B. die Reihenfolge ohne Bedeutungsänderung umkehren.

Comment: Ich denke doch, dass, wenn man ein Komma setzt, beide gleich flektiert werden MÜSSEN, da sie gleiche Funktion haben. Ein Komma heißt, ich kann sie auch vertauschen, aber das kann ich nicht, wenn sie unterschiedliche Endungen haben. Desweiteren könnte ich ja dann auch sowas schreiben: "Eine Kaffee mit dezentem, nussigen, bitterem, edlen Aroma."

Comment: @Emanuel - ich dachte auch, dass sie **müssen**, aber es gibt wohl keine feste Regel und man findet durchaus die gemischte Flexion. Dein langes Beispiel ist immer falsch, da bei der gemischten Flexion nur das erste Adjektiv stark, alle anderen schwach flektiert werden.

Comment: Hast du denn signifikant viele Beispiele für so eine Situation (Komma, gemischt)? Oder stützt du dich hauptsächlich auf den Fakt, dass du keine Regel gefunden hast? Dann würde ich nämlich evtl selbst mal nachgucken, denn es fällt mir schwer zu glauben.

Comment: Im in meiner Antwort verlinkten Artikel finden sich ein paar weitere Beispiele. Naturgemäß ist so etwas extrem schwer zu finden, selbst in Zeiten von Google. Es geht mir eigentlich nur darum, dass es schon gewisse Regeln gibt, dass diese aber nicht unumstritten sind und dass es auch Ausnahmen gibt. Diese müssen dann nicht gleich falsch sein.

Answer (score 3):

Es muss *überheblichem* heißen.

Falls er kein Tippfehler ist, kommt der Fehler vielleicht daher, dass z.B. bei *ihrem überheblichen Verhalten* das zweite Wort trotz Dativ auf n endet. Aber das ist natürlich grammatikalisch etwas anderes. *arrogantem und überheblichem* ist eine Reihung von Wörtern, die grammatikalisch die gleiche Funktion haben (EDIT: das alleine reicht noch nicht, siehe Takkats Antwort), und damit haben sie auch die gleiche Endung.