# Mit gutem roten Wein?

Tags: grammar, adjective, dative, adjective-ending

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler und wohne seit einigen Jahren in Deutschland.

Als ich Deutsch als Fremdsprache gelernt habe, habe ich folgende Regel bzgl. der Beugung von Adjektiven gelernt: Ein oder mehrere Adjektive haben starke Endungen, wenn vor dem ersten Adjektiv kein Artikel, Demonstrativ- oder Possessivpronomen vorkommt. Also: *gute Menschen*, *mit gutem rotem Wein*, *mit frischer weicher Butter*, *neues kaltes Bier*, *lieber alter Freund* usw.

Ich höre aber oft Ausdrücke wie *mit gutem roten Wein* und frage mich, welche Regel hier angewendet wird.

Meine erste Vermutung war, dass es in der Umgangssprache eine weitere Regel gibt. Nach dieser Regel ist es korrekt, wenn das erste Adjektiv in einer Kette eine starke Endung hat und alle anderen die entsprechende schwache Endung. Aber nach dieser Regel müsste man auch sagen können: *mit frischer weichen Butter*, *neues kalte Bier*, usw. Solche Ausdrücke habe ich nie gehört.

Also, ist *mit gutem roten Wein* überhaupt korrekt? Wenn ja, welche Regel wird hier angewendet?

Comment: Related: [Zwei -em-Endungen in Adjektiven hintereinander](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/24228/9551)

Answer (score 11):

Die Vermutung mit der „umgangssprachlichen Sonderregel“ trifft es eigentlich genau, es gibt nur eine weitere Einschränkung: Die Sonderregel gilt nur für den Dativ, und da in erster Linie für Maskulinum und Neutrum.

Es ist also in der Umgangssprache verbreitet, *mit gutem roten Wein*, *mit gutem kühlen Bier* oder *nach kurzem gründlichen Nachdenken* zu sagen; das Phänomen wird auch als *Wechselflexion* bezeichnet. Für die Standardsprache wird das allgemein nicht als korrekt angesehen (es würde also in einem Schulaufsatz vermutlich als Fehler gewertet), hier gilt nur *mit gutem rotem Wein*, *mit gutem kühlem Bier* bzw. *nach kurzem gründlichem Nachdenken* als richtig.

In realen Texten, beispielsweise aus Zeitungen, kommt die Wechselflexion aber sehr häufig vor. Nach einer Untersuchung des Instituts für Deutsche Sprache (s.u.) ist sie in aktuellen Texten sogar in der Mehrheit. Daher wird die Wechselflexion wohl über kurz oder lang auch in der Standardsprache akzeptiert sein.

Etwas anders sieht es beim Dativ Femininum aus: Formulierungen wie *nach langer schweren Krankheit* oder *mit großer inneren Freude* kommen auch vor, aber sehr viel seltener, und werden überwiegend als falsch abgelehnt.

Links:

- Jacqueline Kubczak, [*Mit echtem bayerischem Senf* oder *mit echtem bayerischen Senf*? Flexion bei artikellosen Folgen von Adjektiven](https://web.archive.org/web/20180212025237/http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de:80/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=44), Institut für Deutsche Sprache
- Stephan Bopp, [Kongruenz und Flexionstypen: Zwei aufeinanderfolgende Adjektive](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/index.html?MenuId=Word313#Anchor-Zwei-49575), canoonet

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Erläuterung, wie diese Regel (Wechselflexion) funktioniert. Was ich noch nicht verstehe, ist die Logik dahinter. Wie ist diese Regel entstanden und warum wird sie nur für den Dativ für Maskulinum und Neutrum angewendet? Ich kann keine Logik sehen und finde auch unter der Frage von Barth Zalewski keine Antwort dazu.