# "von großem theoretischem Interesse" oder "von großem theoretischen Interesse"?

Tags: dative

Stellen wie diese bringen mich immer an die Grenzen meiner Sprachkünste. Welche Regeln kann man denn da heranziehen und was stimmt?

> von großem theoretische**m** Interesse

oder

> von großem theoretische**n** Interesse

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/24228/1224 ### http://german.stackexchange.com/q/27650/1224