# Warum „anderen“ anstatt „anderem“?

Tags: pronoun, declension, adjective-ending

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357)*

Mich wundert der folgende Satz:

> Mit keinem **anderen** Fahrzeug … usw

Kann **anderen** durch **anderem** ersetzt werden ?

Comment: "Anderem" nur wenn ohne Artikel im Dativ für Maskulinum und Neutrum: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:anderer

Comment: Aber hier gibt es kein Artikel !

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/27650/1696)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zwei -em-Endungen in Adjektiven hintereinander](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24228/zwei-em-endungen-in-adjektiven-hintereinander)

Comment: @Em1 *keinem* ist mE kein Adjektiv sondern ein artikelartiges Zahlwort. Daher keine Dublette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot be replaced with *anderem* here.

The preposition *mit* requires Dative case ("Mit was/womit..."?). "das Fahrzeug" is neutrum, so in singular dative with indefinite article the construction becomes *Mit keinem anderen Fahrzeug...*, see [here](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm)

Comment: Ach so ,, 
auch so : Mit keiner anderen Frau ? 
Geht es so ?

Comment: @Ehab Das ist auch korrekt.

Answer (score 3):

Adjektive können auf zwei verschiedene Arten gebeugt werden: stark oder schwach. Zu allem Überfluss gibt es dann auch noch die *gemischte Deklination* sowie die prädikativ verwendete Nulldeklination. Aber der Reihe nach.

## Starke Deklination

Diese wird verwendet, wenn vor dem Adjektiv (und also auch vor dem Substantiv) *kein* Artikel steht.

> ### Nominativ
>
> Ander**er** Käse liegt auf dem Tisch. (maskulin)
>   Ander**e** Milch steht auf dem Tisch. (feminin)
>   Ander**es** Brot liegt auf dem Tisch. (neutrum)
>   Ander**e** Sorten liegen auf dem Tisch. (Plural)
>
> ### Dativ
>
> Mit ander**em** Käse schmeckt es besser. (maskulin)
>   Mit ander**er** Milch schmeckt es besser. (feminin)
>   Mit ander**em** Brot schmeckt es besser. (neutrum)
>   Mit ander**en** Sorten schmeckt es besser. (Plural)
>
> ### Akkusativ
>
> Ich esse ander**en** Käse. (maskulin)
>   Ich trinke ander**e** Milch. (feminin)
>   Ich esse ander**es** Brot. (neutrum)
>   Ich esse ander**e** Sorten. (Plural)

## Schwache Deklination

Diese wird verwendet, wenn ein *bestimmter* Artikel vor dem Adjektiv steht.

> ### Nominativ
>
> Der ander**e** Käse liegt auf dem Tisch. (maskulin)
>   Die ander**e** Milch steht auf dem Tisch. (feminin)
>   Das ander**e** Brot liegt aut dem Tisch. (neutrum)
>   Die ander**en** Sorten liegen auf dem Tisch. (Plural)
>
> ### Dativ
>
> Mit dem ander**en** Käse schmeckt es besser. (maskulin)
>   Mit der ander**en** Milch schmeckt es besser. (feminin)
>   Mit dem ander**en** Brot schmeckt es besser. (neutrum)
>   Mit den ander**en** Sorten schmeckt es besser. (Plural)
>
> ### Akkusativ
>
> Ich esse den ander**en** Käse. (maskulin)
>   Ich trinke die ander**e** Milch. (feminin)
>   Ich esse das ander**e** Brot.  (neutrum)
>   Ich esse die ander**en** Sorten. (Plural)

## Gemischte Deklination

Diese wird verwendet, wenn ein unbestimmter Artikel vor dem Substantiv steht. Das kann *eine(r)/(s)* sein, oder aber auch *kein* oder andere.

> ### Nominativ
>
> Ein ander**er** Käse liegt auf dem Tisch. (maskulin)
>   Eine ander**e** Milch liegt auf dem Tisch. (feminin)
>   Ein ander**es** Brot liegt auf dem Tisch. (neutrum)
>   Keine ander**en** Sorten liegen auf dem Tisch. (Plural)
>
> ### Dativ
>
> Mit einem ander**en** Käse schmeckt es besser. (maskulin)
>   Mit einer ander**en** Milch schmeckt es besser. (feminin)
>   Mit einem ander**en** Brot schmeckt es besser. (neutrum)
>   Mit keinen ander**en** Sorten schmeckt es besser. (Plural)
>
> ### Akkusativ
>
> Ich esse einen ander**en** Käse. (maskulin)
>   Ich trinke eine ander**e** Milch. (feminin)
>   Ich esse ein ander**es** Brot. (neutrum)
>   Ich esse keine ander**en** Sorten. (Plural)

## Nulldeklination

Diese wird verwendet, wenn das Adjektiv prädikativ verwendet wird, das heißt, mit einem Verb an das Substantiv verbunden ist. Hier wird das Adjektiv in seiner Grundform ungebeugt verwendet.

> Der Käse ist anders.
>   Die Milch ist anders.
>   Das Brot ist anders.
>   Die Sorten sind anders.

---

Weil *keinem* sich wie der unbestimmte Artikel verhält, muss man gemischte Deklination anwenden. *Fahrzeug* ist neutrum, die Präposition verlangt den Dativ. Deswegen muss es unbedingt folgendermaßen lauten:

> Mit keinem anderen Fahrzeug.

Nur ohne *kein* kann es *anderem* sein.