# Grammatik: »einziges schöne Mädchen« oder »einziges schönes Mädchen«?

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective

Wie heißt es richtig?

> einziges schöne Mädchen

oder

> einziges schöne**s** Mädchen

Ich tippe auf Letzteres.

Comment: Und was ist mit "einzige schöne Mädchen"? (Du bist das einzige schöne Mädchen im Raum.)

Comment: *Du bist ein einzig schönes Mädchen* - geht auch.

Comment: Siehe auch [diese Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/24228/1696).

Comment: Bitte mehr Kontext! Es sollte zumindest ein ganzer Satz sein. Wie sollen wir wissen, welcher Fall hier vorliegt?

Answer (score 5):

Ohne Artikel: "einziges schönes Mädchen"

Mit unbestimmtem Artikel: "ein einziges schönes Mädchen"

Mit bestimmtem Artikel: "das einzige schöne Mädchen"

Answer (score -2):

Auch »einziges schöne Mädchen« kann richtig sein, etwa in der Überschrift eines Zeitungsartikels:

> Einziges schöne Mädchen der Klasse wurde gemobbt

Comment: nope... das müsste dann "Einziges schönes Mädchen" heissen...

Comment: @Torsten Link: Ich halte den Satz für eine gültige Kurzform von: »Das einzige schöne Mädchen der Klasse wurde gemobbt«