# Adjective declension trouble

Tags: adjective-ending

The following sentence is from a manual of a video game describing the properties and effects of certain abilities. The past participle/adjective *ausgeteilt* in the following sentence might be a typo, but I can't be sure:

> Effekte: Ziele angreifen (bei ausgeteiltem kritischen Treffer)

In this case, *bei* is dative, therefore it should follow that the adjective *ausgeteilt* become *ausgeteilten*.

My question is: Am I missing something here? Is this just a typo or is there merely some grammatical rule I am not aware of.

Comment: It is a grammatical rule, but a rather complicated: it is Wechselflexion and Parallelflexion.

Comment: If Treffer is considered singular, and as it is masculine, you‘ll get an „m“.

Comment: I am stunned about the *technical ressources* people use for learning German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase is correct as it is.

You are right that *bei* requires dative case. Since the noun *Treffer* is masculine and singular, the adjectives describing this noun needs to get the **singular, masculine, dative ending** as well.

Furthermore, there is no article-like word preceding the adjectives. Thus, we need to take **strong inflexion** (in contrast to the weak inflexion in *bei dem ausgeteilten kritischen Treffer*).
 Thus, we end up with [*ausgeteiltem*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/ausgeteilt:A).

---

How can we know that *Treffer* is singular here, since the plural is *die Treffer*? We can tell, because plural dative would be [*den Treffern*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/Treffer).

And why isn't it *kritischem*? Well, that is debatable. Usually, you use the same inflexion for multiple adjectives in a row (this is called [*Parallelflexion*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/index.html?MenuId=Word313#Anchor-Zwei-49575)). Applying this, one could write *bei ausgeteiltem kritischem Treffer*.

However, it is possible to signal subordination of one adjective by using weak inflexion (this is called *Wechselflexion*, see the accepted answer for [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24228/zwei-em-endungen-in-adjektiven-hintereinander) for example). This is, what happened here: there wouldn't be a critical hit, if there wasn't an allotted hit. Thus, it is correct to write *bei ausgeteiltem kritischen Treffer*.

Answer (score 2):

Correct is:

> bei ausgeteiltem kritischem Treffer

Because there is no article, strong adjective declension is used, so the ending is -em.

With an article things are different:

> bei einem ausgeteilten kritischen Treffer

Here we have weak declenstion because an article is present.

Actually there is some disagreement whether *ausgeteiltem kritischen Treffer* is correct, that is, if is OK to restrict the strong declension to the first adjective. There is a discussion of this at [Bei gutem, schönem, heiterem Wetter: dreimal em](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2010/04/19/bei-gutem-schonem-heiterem-wetter-dreimal-em/)